# Integrating the exponential of a complex quadratic matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

### Problem statement

I'm trying to do a discretized path integral/functional integral. The integral that I'm stuck with is of the form

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathrm{d}^3\vec{x}_1\, \mathrm{d}^3\vec{x}_2\, \ldots\, \mathrm{d}^3\vec{x}_N\ \exp\left\{X^t \cdot (A + iB) \cdot X\right\}
$$

where $X$ is a column 'vector' of all $\vec{x}_i$ vectors: $X = (\vec{x}_1\ \vec{x}_2\ \ldots\ \vec{x}_N)$, $A$ is a real symmetric pentadiagonal matrix and $B$ is a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix. The integration is over all real space.

### Additional info

The $B$ matrix actually depends on lots of real scalar parameters $\lambda_1 \ldots \lambda_N$ that will later be integrated over as well (over all space). These are Lagrange multipliers to force some constraint on $X$, hence the $i$.

I guess that for the vast majority of these parameters, the complete matrix $C \equiv A + iB$ will be diagonalizable (expect for a few pathological cases, of measure zero(?)). In that case, it can be written as $C = Z^t D Z$ with some diagonal matrix $D$ and $Z$ a complex matrix with $Z^tZ=1$ ($C$ is symmetric).

If $Z$ were real, then a change of variables to $X' = ZX$ would turn the integration into a product of simple 1D gaussians over the diagonal entries of D. However, $Z$ is complex-valued (and D isn't necessarily real either(?)), so I guess that this won't quite work.

All pointers are welcome!